# Sum previous rows in column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking for a solution to sum previous rows in a calculated column.

Sample data:

product | sales | cumulative

000001 | 2000 | 2000

000001 | 2000 | 4000

000002 | 1500 | 1500

000001 | 2000 | 6000

000002 | 1500 | 3000

Could anyone help me with the DAX please.

Comment: It is not clear from the question what you are trying to achieve. Please provide the expected result.

Comment: @Acarbalacar The expected result is a cumulative sales amount per product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do

**step 1)**
I would create a new ordinal column with a sequential number for each product group

```
index = 
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        Sales,
        EARLIER ( Sales[Product] ) = Sales[Product]
    ),
    Sales[Sales],
    ,
    ASC
)
```

**Step 2)**
I create the Running Totals column that shows the running totals by group

```
Running Totals = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM (Sales[Sales]),
    FILTER(
        Sales,
        Sales[Product] = EARLIER ( Sales[Product]) 
        && Sales[index] <= EARLIER ( Sales[index])
    )
)
```

this is the result

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Unfornately it won't work as my dataset is too large. Is this also possible as a measure?